# Show a button on a previous activity when going back from current activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to visible a edit button on my previous activity by going back using back button. But when I am using

```
        @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // finish the current activity
                finish();

            }
```

on my current activity, it is going back to previous activity, but edit button doesn't become visible.

If I am using `onResume` on previous activity

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        btnEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

then it's always visible, no matter if the activity is resuming or created for the first time.

I am new in Android development, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html especially the `startActivityForResult` part.

Comment: No matter how you go back to the previous activity, `onResume()` will **always** be called on it. The description of your problem doesn't sound 100% correct. Can you provide more information or more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

When you start the Activity, instead of `startActivity(intent)` use `startActivityForResult(intent, 1989)` (The 1989 can be whatever int you want).

When you return from the new Activity, before calling `finish()` do the following:

```
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("resultBool", true);

        //Null checks, not strictly neccescary 

            if (getParent() == null)
            {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            }

    finish();
```

Then in your first Activity override `onActivityResult()` like so:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            // The int you initially used
            if (requestCode == 1989)
            {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    boolean result = data.getBooleanExtra("resultBool", false)

                    if (result)
                      //Show the button now

                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Joss it's a great help.it's working like a charm...   :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a boolean variable which can be set to true when you finish and make a check with this boolean in your onResume method

Answer (score 0):

Override onRestart() method

```
@Override
protected void onRestart () {
    super.onResume();
    btnEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Or start Activity with

```
startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

method and override

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode,resultCode,data);
    btnEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```